# simple 2d array using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, matrix

I'm following this [Angular tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) to make a simple web application. The end of this portion asks me to create an 8x8 table adding an additional `ng-repeat`.

I tried to simply follow the pattern I'd do in something like JavaScript to create a matrix:

```
var ary = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   ary[i] = [];
   for (var j =0; j < 8; j++) {
       ary[i][j] = value;
   }
}
```

It's just outputting one row of numbers when I try in Angular:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
        <tr ng-repeat="p in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
            <td>
                {{i}}{{p}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @PetrAveryanov That doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put tr> inside another tr>

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
            <td  ng-repeat="p in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
                {{i}}{{p}}
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Petr did you check the output of this? It's not correct

Comment: i have no idea what output is correct http://plnkr.co/edit/itB5GyJk6WrulEwjdAI0?p=preview -- seems ok